# how to use Golang to shell command with given sudo password

Tags: shell, datetime, go, command, sudo

I'd like to use a piece of command line to set datetime in Go,
but the following code failed

```
datetime := "2021-06-17 18:20:41.8"
sudoPassword := "xxxxx"
app := "echo"
arg0 := sudoPassword
arg1 := "|sudo -S"
arg2 := "date"
arg3 := "-s"
arg4 := "\"" + datetime + "\""
cmd := exec.Command(app, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

Is there a correct way to do this? Fill the password automatically like in Python

```
os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudoPassword, command))
```

Comment: *how* did your code fail? with what error etc.?

Comment: @mrfuppes That code just showed the current system datetime, although cmd.Run() returns a nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue with your code is that `exec.Command` execs commands directly without a wrapping shell, but you have constructed a shell pipeline.  You can manually specify a stdin reader for use with sudo, though.

```
    cmd := exec.Command("sudo", "-S", "--", "cat", "/etc/shadow")
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("mysecretpassword") // your password fed directly to sudo's stdin
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work. Could you please explain why and how to use the wrapping shell? Would the code be more compact like a single-line style?

Comment: The shell interposes itself between your set of commands and parses it as a string.  You can use shell pipeline syntax then. You would do something like: `exec.Command("sh", "-c" "echo " + sudoPassword  + " | date -S")`  or something.  It can be occasionally convenient to shell out, but can also cause [problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection).